# Installing Magma and LPF in Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I've been trying to install Magma in Pharo, but have had absolutely no luck. This is the stuff I've tried so far:

1. Installing with Monticello from `squeaksource.com/MagmaTester` -- Syntax error in MaObjectSerializer >> setUpClassDefinitionProcessing.
2. Installing from Universe -- the image hangs, apparently getting stuck in an infinite redirect loop while trying to hit `installer.pbwiki.com/f/mc15.st`.
3. Installing LPF directly with `HTTPSocket httpFileIn: 'ftp.squeak.org/3.11/bob/LPF.st'` -- I get a syntax error, because apparently one of the Installer files is in Unicode (or at least each character is unexpectedly double-wide).

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have more answers if you ask in Magma mailing list or even in Pharo, but not here.

Comment: If you get an answer on the mailing lists would you post it here please?

Comment: No. StackOverflow provides a bad fit for smalltalk.  The knowledge is and stays on the mailing lists untill we find something better.

Comment: This should really have been a comment, since it doesn't really answer the question asked.